# SQLite and System.Data version incompatibility

Tags: .net, sqlite, compact-framework

I have a .NET Compact 3.5 Forms project that I'm using VS 2008 with.
I added the System.Data.SQLite.dll to my project after downloading it from here.[SQLite Downloads](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Now, when I try to use things like `SQLiteConnection`, `SQLiteCommand`, or `SQLiteDataReader` I get the following error on build-->

`The type System.Data.Common.DbCommand is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly System.Data, Version/2.0.0.0`

I checked and, by default, VS added a reference to `System.Data, Version=3.5.0.0` on project creation.  So, what am I missing?  I wouldn't include references to both, would I?  It seems like SQLite is compatible with 3.5....

Comment: Did you install the version of SQLite for the Net Framework 3.5?

Comment: Yes.  I installed this one --> Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 3.5 SP1) @ http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: So VS added a reference to System.Data 3.5.0.0, but your error on build says it wants a reference to System.Data 2.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing it added the 3.5 reference because I am targeting CF 3.5...?

Comment: So, My problem was that I downloaded the wrong SQLite dll.  I should have grabbed the ones for Compact 2013 further down the page.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.